# stock feed data structure

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

What would be the most appropriate data structure for the following scenario:
The stock quotes (scrip code,price) would need to be collated.Every hour,the top N scrips(highest quote) need to be reported in descending order.
Potentially,the number of quotes can be millions within the hour.
An arraylist with comparator will be a disaster due to the frequent inserts.
A TreeSet seems to be an option - but can someone suggest a better structure,if there is one.
(And that can include building on a generic data structure ,rather than using the existing java collection classes too.)

Answer (score 0):

I can't suggest anything besides `TreeSet`, but I can point out a possible optimization - it seems like any quote that is less than the top Nth quote so far doesn't need to be added at all. This would mean the tree was at most N in size, rather than unbounded.

For example:

```
final int n = ...;
final NavigableSet<Quote> topNQuotes = new TreeSet<Quote>();

void addQuote(Quote quote) {
    //if the Set of quotes has reached N,
    if (topNQuotes.size() == n) {
        //get the greatest Quote that is less than this one
        Quote lowerQuote = topNQuotes.lower(quote);
        //if no such Quote was found in the Set, quit without adding
        if (lowerQuote == null) {
            return;
        }
        //otherwise remove and discard the lowest Quote from the Set
        topNQuotes.pollFirst();
    }
    //add the new Quote to the Set
    topNQuotes.add(quote);
}
```

Note that this example isn't thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks - I was looking to see if we can better TreeSet by building on any generic data structure.The heap doesnt seem to be an optimum for extracting beyond 1 - owing to the re-orientation every time.

Answer (score 0):

From personal experience writing a real-time price feed, if speed is an issue it is worth it to take up some extra memory. I would honestly suggest hashing your price feed by price or order ID if that is at all feasible.

Also, if I understand you correctly, you want to display the top N prices for a symbol. While there may be millions of orders over these N prices, they can each be collated into one of N price levels. Thus, if you make a price level object, your data structure would just have to shuffle around pointers to these price level objects. In this case, as long as N is not too large (as there aren't usually that many price levels for a particular symbol) an array might be plenty fast with locality.

I would also think that using a circular array would be a decent solution for displaying a price-level book, if you don't want to hash it. That way insertion at the front (i.e. the lowest price) and the end (the highest) should be both be constant time on average. You can also use a shadow array to ensure O(1) constant time insertion.

Comment: A  minor misunderstanding - I am not looking to report top N quotes for a scrip;but top N quotes overall in the past hour.I shouldnt need a re-sort with every new entry feeding in;and be able to get the needed N quotes in descending order.